# Win32 MessageBox cutting off text

Tags: winapi, text, messagebox

When trying to display a win32 dialog using the MessageBox function, the text seems to be getting cut off, but oddly enough this only happens when building for release, which is leaving me completely baffled.

code this occurs with:

```
wchar_t filepath[ MAX_PATH ];
GetModuleFileName( NULL, filepath, MAX_PATH );

wchar_t* fnp = PathFindFileName(filepath);

wchar_t filename[MAX_PATH];
swprintf(filename, MAX_PATH, L"%ls", fnp);
printf("%ls", filename);
wchar_t* pwc;
pwc = wcsstr(filename,L".exe");
wcsncpy(pwc,L"_real.exe\0",10);

if(!file_exists(filename)){
    wchar_t buff[] = L"unable to start because %ls cannot be found.";
    wchar_t say[MAX_PATH+sizeof(buff)-3];
    swprintf(say, wcslen(say), buff, filename);
    MessageBoxW(NULL, say, L"Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is where you write `wcslen(say)`. At the point where you write it, `say` has not been initialized and so `wcslen(say)` invokes UB. You meant to write `sizeof(say)/sizeof(wchar_t)`.

On top of that, `sizeof(buff)` is the size in `char` units. But the array has `wchar_t` units. So that code is wrong.

You want something like this:

```
wchar_t buff[] = L"unable to start because %ls cannot be found.";
wchar_t say[MAX_PATH + sizeof(buff)/sizeof(wchar_t) - 3];
swprintf(say, sizeof(say)/sizeof(wchar_t), buff, filename);
```

Comment: This seems to have fixed the issue but out of sheer curiosity, you wouldn't happen to know why it works in the debug environment, would you?

Comment: It's undefined behaviour what happens. Anything can happen, even the program working.

Comment: If you don't care about portability you can use `_countof(say)` as an alternative.